# How to add close button on confirmation box using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js . I have a confirmation box . My code is like -

```
 $scope.confirmback = function() {
   $confirm({text: 'Do you want to save this document?', title: 'Confirmation', ok: 'Save', cancel: 'Exit'}, {backdrop: 'static'})
   .then(function() {
     $scope.updateDocument();
   })
   .catch(function(){
     _htmlEditorModal.modal('hide');
   });
 };
```

So , I want to have a close button which will close the confirmation box on the same page. I have tried different ways : I can have `X` as a close button, or just a simple button on which it will close the confirmation box.

Comment: Would the close button have the same functionality as the cancel button? Are you using `angular-confirm`?

Comment: Yes I am using angular-confirm . No, Close button will close only confirm box ,while cancel will close the page on which confirm box applied.

Comment: Sorry, I am still unclear what the close button should do. Could you maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: See, Close button will only close the confirmation box. If you are deleting something then one confrimBox appears, behind that will be the list from which you are deleting . so , close will close the confirm box and not the list from which you are deleting . But cancel will close list as well as confirm-box.